# DataGridView change a cell content that's condition up to another cell

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a list of `products` and I am trying to add them into a datagridview. Each product has a property like id, name, brand, price, stockAmount, isPackaged, and product type properties. What i want is to make invisible the IsPackaged boolean and if that boolean is true change the productType to "packaged" if it is not make it "unpackaged", I dont want in each insertion typing the packageType. However, I get an error like "The name IsPackaged does not exist in the current context"

To hide the isPackage column i found a code that works fine:   `dataGridView1.Columns["IsPackaged"].Visible = false;`

```
list.Add(new Product()
            {
                ID = 4,
                Name = "Ice Cream",
                Brand = "Magnum",
                Price = 12,
                IsPackaged = true,
                ProductType = IsPackaged ? "Packaged" : "Unpackaged" , //Here is the error
                StockAmount = 50,
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be mistaken, but it looks like `ProductType` should be a “non-settable” property since it is based on the `IsPackaged` property. In other words, whatever, `IsPacked` IS will determine what `ProductType`’s value is.

In its current state the two variables appear redundant and could be set into an inconsistent state. Example… the user could set `IsPackaged` to `false`, then turn around and set `ProductType` to “Packaged”! How would you know which one was correct?

You may want to change the `ProductType` of the `Product` class to maintain a consistent state like…

```
public string ProductType {
  get {
    return IsPackaged ? "Packaged" : "Unpackaged";
  }
}
```

This way the “ProductType” is never “directly" set since it depends on what value `IsPackaged` is.

This property will be displayed in the grid; however, the user will not be able to “change” it. And since you are making the `IsPackaged` column invisible, then there will be no way for the user to change it. So, I will assume there is missing info in your question in regard to “how” this is supposed to work. If it is for purely “display” purposes, then it should work. If you want the user to be able to “change” the `IsPackaged` value, then I would guess that it should be displayed to the user. Again, this is not clear.

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly fine. How couldn't I think that? it's such a simple trick. Thanks again.